# Can I use a Broadcom USB Bluetooth dongle with Atmega328P MCU for wireless communication? I can't find the pinout of the USB anywhere

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, atmega328p

Here is an image of the device I have:

[image: Image Source: Google]

However, the chip used in my dongle is BCM2035. It is a standard USB Bluetooth Dongle. I have never used a Bluetooth with an MCU before. I'm guessing the use of Vcc, Gnd, Rx and Tx pins. This dongle offers me USB interface as you can see, which is connected to 6 pins on the board. I am not sure what all these pins are and how should I interface.

Comment: The pinout for USB A connectors is easy to find. As for using the module, best to take a look at the linux driver to see how hard it is going to be.

Comment: @Jon I didnt get it. Is it required to study a driver for interfacing and creating my own code to communicate with the module, say, for switching some led on and off? I am on a dual-boot Win10 and lubuntu btw. 
I was assuming playing with data to manipulate Atmega328p pin outputs.

Comment: There are two parts to getting it to work. The first is that you need to be able to communicate with the dongle over the USB protocol. Once you've gotten that working you will be able to send raw commands/data to the Bluetooth chip. But you need to know what proprietary protocol this uses. You might be able to get this from Broadcom. It may require you to implement the upper layers of the Bluetooth stack. If the latter then it isn't worth bothering with. To get an idea of what is required, I would take a look at the Linux driver.

Comment: Also the chip you plan to use does not have a USB host. So you won't be able to use it to communicate with the dongle.

Comment: Did you open the Atmega328P datasheet? Did you see a mention of a USB interface somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could connect Vcc, Gnd, Rx and Tx pins (you probably want other pins so you still have Rx/Tx for its normal use). But then you have to implement the USB on-wire protocol including the timing. You have to implement an USB controller by manipulating the Rx and Tx pin fast enough.

While it probably works (not sure the cpu is fast enough) you won't have time left to do much else. It's a better idea to buy a bluetooth module without the USB part and connect it directly. There are bluetooth modules with a plain serial input/output. Those you can connect directly to Rx/Tx without having to emulate USB.